# The determinant of the sum of normal matrices

Tags: matrices, open-problems, determinants

Given two normal matrices $A,B\in M_n({\mathbb C})$ 
whose respective spectra are $(\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n})$ and
$(\beta_{1},\ldots,\beta_{n})$, is it true that $\det(A+B)$ belongs to 
the convex hull of the set of numbers
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(\alpha_i+\beta_{\sigma(i)}),$$
as $\sigma$ runs over the set ${\mathfrak S}_n$ of permutations of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ ?

**Nota**. It is known (see [Exercise 101](http://www.umpa.ens-lyon.fr/~serre/DPF/exobis.pdf)) that the trace of $AB$ belongs to the convex hull of the 
set of numbers
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_{j}\beta_{\sigma(j)},\qquad\sigma\in {\mathfrak S}_n.$$

Comment: Interesting question, I hope some one will provide a solution.

Answer (score 15):

This claim is nothing but the well-known *Marcus and de Oliveira* conjecture, which has been open since 1973 or earlier.

[Reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20110105040858/http://math.ecnu.edu.cn/%7Ezhan/HangzhouZhan_beamerhandout.pdf): Open Problems in Matrix Theory, X. Zhan.

For the simpler case of Hermitian matrices, the claim holds; a slightly more general case seems to be the paper *"The validity of the Marcus-de Oliveira conjecture for essentially Hermitian matrices."*

PS: you might want to add the "open problem" tag to your question.

Comment: Thank you. I new that de Oliveira was concerned, but I did not succeed to find a paper of him about this, and I did not know about Markus' role. I'll wait to see if someone has some newer information. At least, I don't have the answer. As a rule, I don't ask questions of which I know the answer.

Comment: The link is now broken, unfortunately.